# Create 2 Column from Fullwidth Container-Fluid in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create two column with 100% width from bootstrap 3 framework. I tried to create, but it shows some padding between right and left positions.

In my code left column will be used to show google map and right side will be used to contact form.

How to remove padding? i need a full width row..

**Here it is my code.**

```
<section id="contact">
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
     </div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
     </div class="col-md-6"> ... </div>
    </div>

</div>
</section>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
--------------------------------
              |                     
              |
              |
              |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you mean this:

```css
#contact > .container-fluid > .row > div { border: 1px dashed #ddd;}

#contact > .container-fluid > .row > div:first-child { padding-right: 0;}

#contact > .container-fluid > .row > div:last-child { padding-left: 0;}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<section id="contact">
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6"> map </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6"> contact form </div>
    </div>

</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you! :) @DineshKumar

Comment: Can you up answer like "this answer is useful" pls. thanks! )

Answer (score 0):

The below link help you to achieve your layout using bootstrap:-

google Map with Contact Form

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/contact-us

Comment: This does not use `container-fluid` but just plain `container`.